# What is the difference between object identifier and record id in database?

Tags: database, oracle11g

what is the difference between object identifier(OID) in object relational model and a record id(RID) in relational model ?

Comment: You mean other than the OID identifies an object and the RID identifies a record?

Comment: no.but like to know other than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both serve the same purpose but in different scopes.
Record is declared inside pl/sql block but object is declared in database. This implies that record is a pl/sql block type while object is schema object.

```
declare
type c is record(a number, b number);
begin
---
---
---
end;

create type subtype1 is object(a number, b number);
```

When Oracle constructs a REF to a row object, the constructed REF is made up of the *object identifier*, some metadata of the object table, and, optionally, the *ROWID*.

The size of a REF in a column of REF type depends on the storage properties associated with the column. For example, if the column is declared as a REF WITH ROWID, Oracle stores the ROWID in the REF column. The *ROWID* hint is ignored for object references in constrained REF columns.

If column is declared as a REF with a *SCOPE* clause, the column is made smaller by omitting the object table metadata and the *ROWID*. A scoped REF is 16 bytes long.